# Finding A String Between A String REGEX

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm trying to find a string between a larger string ("text")(?) and even though this function works well in most cases it requires the text to be fully tidied. In simpler words: it doesn't find a string within a text with multiple (or even singular?) newlines.

```
public function f( $s, $x, $y ) {
    preg_match_all( "~\Q$x\E(.*?)\Q$y\E~", $s, $r );
    return $r[ 1 ];
}
```

Any ideas on how to make it find any string within any text?

Comment: @AlanMoore Hello. Could you, please, take a look at this comment of mine (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940385/whats-the-difference-between-namespaces-and-names/20940435#comment31450926_20940435) . The preceding and following comment of this linked comment concern the point to know if a namespace IS a dictionary or IS REPRESENTED AS a dictionary. I remembered that a long time ago you explained me that a module namespace isn't a dictionary. Could you read the comments in the link and  give what you know about the subject, please ?

Comment: @eyquem: I don't recall ever weighing in on the subject of namespaces in Python.  And if I did, I shouldn't have; I know practically nothing about Python.

Answer (score 0):

Activate the `s` flag:

```
preg_match_all( "~\Q$x\E(.*?)\Q$y\E~s", $s, $r );
                                    ^
                         ___________|
```

With `s` flag, dot will match newlines.