# Whats the difference between namespaces and names?

Tags: python

I'm assuming the namespace is the allotted place in memory in which the name is to be stored. Or are they the same thing?

Comment: Don't assume. [Read](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/scopes.html).

Comment: [2.7 docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Answer (score 0):

Names are what can be traditionally thought of as "variables".

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

Both `a` and `b` are "names".  If you try to reference a name that hasn't been set yet, you'll get a `NameError`:

```
>>> print c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

Namespaces are the places where names live.  Typically this is a module.  Each module (file) has it's own namespace -- Or it's own set of names which map to a corresponding *value* (`a->1, b -> 2` in my example above).  You can "merge" module namespaces in different ways using python's `import` functionality.

```
import foo  # bring foo into the current namespace
from foo import *  # bring all of the names in foo's namespace into the current namespace
```

Classes can also be considered a namespace although you can't import the names directly into your module namespace without some work.

```
class Namespace(object):
    pass

namespace = Namespace()
namespace.a = 1
namespace.b = 2
```

---

As pointed out in some of the discussion in the comments, I ought to mention that namespaces in python are *usually* implemented by a dictionary since those are well suited to mapping names to values/objects.  On a class, (or class instance), you can access the dictionary via `ClassName.__dict__` or `instance.__dict__` and you can do the same with a module:  `module.__dict__` if `module` is imported.

At a generic/language agnostic level, I think of a namespace as a way to bind a group of related names (and their associated values) together and to prevent those names from getting mixed up with similar names in a different namespace.  e.g. I can have `foo.something` and `bar.something`.  Both names are `something`, but they live in different namespaces (`foo` and `bar` respectively) so we can tell them apart.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and hasty reply, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You didn't want to write _"Classes can also be considered a namespace"_ but _"A class has a namespace implemented by a dictionary object."_  as [here in the doc](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), did you ?

Comment: @eyquem -- well ... if you want to go down that road, modules also "have a namespace implemented by a dictionary object.  No?

Comment: Not me. It's in the doc. And yes , a module have a namespace implemented as a dictionary object, it is written in the same page whose I gave the link to. Is there a problem considering that modules, classes, instances , etc have namespaces ? Your comment sounds like a reproach. Is it one ?

Comment: @eyquem -- No, not a reproach.  It's just that the semantics get a little muddy here.  I'm not sure that they're *clearly* defined anywhere so it doesn't make a lot of sense to me to split hairs on whether the class is a namespace, or whether the class's `__dict__` is the namespace ...

Comment: ``__dict__`` of an object is certainly a namespace, it's written in the doc. But I understand what you want to mean: a class has attributes (data members and methods) and they are the intersting things in a class (or instance, or module, etc) and the word 'namespace' is handy to underline this. However it isn't a rigorous use of this word, since it lacks something: it doesn't express that the attributes follow a special functionning under the control of the interpreter. Saying an object is a namespace is less meaningful than saying it is a class. A dict has less functionning than a class

Comment: By the way, I've just upvoted on of your more upvoted answers, on gnuplot, to respond to your desire of a gold gnuplot badge expressed in your profile. Do you remind it ? :)

Comment: @eyquem -- I've been giving your points a lot of thought.  The docs state that the namespace is implemented via the object's `__dict__` which (in my opinion) is slightly different than the namespace *is* the object's `__dict__`.  However, noting that is definitely worthwhile and I've updated my answer slightly to reflect that.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: In [this page](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) the expression _"has a namespace implemented by a dictionary object"_ is employed for modules and classes descriptions, while the expression _"implemented as a dictionary"_ is employed in the instances description. I never remarked this slight difference until now, and I don't know if it has a real meaning. But not _"via a dictionary"_ by the way. However, you may be right because there was long ago a guy who correted me saying .... (cont.)

Comment: .... that a module's namespace given by ``globals()`` WASN'T the dictionary but was REPRESENTED AS the dictionary returned by ``globals()``. I hope I remind this correctly. I didn't speak of that in my answer because it's a very specialized point on which I'm not so much competent. I would be very interested to learn the final word in this story.

Comment: I've found who was the man who said me that, it is Alan Moore, if I don't do an error. I think I will write to him to draw his attention on these comments, hoping that he will be able to explain this affair.

Comment: `globals()` does nothing more than return the current module's `__dict__`.  The documentation on `globals` states that.  But, as I said in my last paragraph a namespace is a *concept*, not really a hard and fast *thing*.  You could use a bare dict as a namespace if you really wanted to.  It's just a way to make it so that you can have mutiple names for objects and to make sure that names to different objects don't accidentally "collide".

Comment: A namespace is a concept, I agree, that's what I wanted to say in my answer but I didn't find the word, I used 'theoretical' instead, but concept is better. However, this concept has necessarily an implementation to be oprative. - I can't say more than what I've already written.

Answer (score 0):

A namespace is a theoretical space in which the link between names and objects are situated: that is what is called a mapping between the names and the objects.
Names are the identifiers written in a script.
Objects are structures of bits lying in the memory.
The data structure that implements this theoretical namespace is a dictionnary. "Implements" means that it is the object that holds this data in the bits of the memory.
But the objects that this dictionary references are not grouped all together in a delimited portion of the memory, they are lying everywhere in the memory, it's the role of the dictionary to know how to find any of them with just a name at start when a name is encountered by the interpreter.
That's why I wrote it is a theoretical space, though it has a concrete existence in the memory. It is theoretical because the fact that several objects disseminated at different places in the memory can be considered to belong to one namespace is the result of the under-the-hood functionning of the Python interpreter, that is to say its [data model](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#data-model) and its [execution model](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#execution-model)

In fact, things are more complex, under the hood there is a symbol table in the game. But I'm not enough competent concerning the C implementation of Python to say more. And by the way, people rarely allude to the symbol table.

However, I hope that the above explanation will shed some light in your mind concerning the subject of namespace.

Answer (score -1):

'I'm assuming the namespace is the allotted place in memory in which the name is to be stored.'
yep.